# Python SQLite3 storing a value from a record into a variable

Tags: database, sqlite

I have created a database using SQLite3 in Python with the fields, `ID` which is a primary key, `Username`, `Password`, and `progress`. I have successfully created the login system that inserts if no identical records are found, and the login system. The issue that I am having is after that, getting the specific progress of the individual. I have searched which gave me a record like this:

```
(1,Username,Password,0)
```

But the issue is getting the `0` value into a variable. Any help is much appreciated.

My code for this particular section:

```
Temp = ""
for x in Connection.execute("SELECT * FROM LoginDetails WHERE username = ? 
                           AND password = ?", (Login_Username, Login_Password)):
    Temp = x
```

Answer (score 0):

The `execute` function returns a cursor. Iterating over the cursors returns rows. Each row contains multiple column values (or a single column, but in every case, a row is a tuple).

You could access the fourth column with `x[3]`, but when you want only a single column, you should write the query so that you do not fetch unneeded values:

```
for row in connection.execute('''SELECT Progress
                                 FROM LoginDetails
                                 WHERE username = ?
                                   AND password = ?''',
                              [Login_Username, Login_Password]):
    progress = row[0]
else:
    progress = ''
```

Comment: Thank you for this, worked well, did not realise SELECT Progress FROM LoginDetails would select all records.